# Raising a float to a certain power in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

I have a variable `x` of type `float` which should be raised to a certain power `p`. If `x` was a `double` I could have used `Math.pow(x, p)`. Is it possible to calculate `x^p` so that the result will also be a `float`?

Comment: Use the same method. It'll be implicitly cast to `double`.

Comment: What is the problem with converting to double?

Comment: Not with the standard JDK. But why don't you just use `double`?

Comment: If we convert float to double we rise accuracy and propably the result will not be the same (?).

Comment: @MarounMaroun: You're right, but I also want the result to be a float. I wasn't clear about it when posting the question, but I've made an edit to make it explicit.

Comment: @fge: The reason for not using doubles is that I'm extending a framework that's using floats exclusively.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Please post your comments as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @snakile: [Done.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21758629/298225).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evaluating `pow` in `double` and converting to `float` will almost always produce the same results as evaluating a `float` implementation of `pow`.  To see this, consider the exact mathematical value of *x*<sup>*p*</sup>. If, using round-to-nearest mode, it is correctly rounded to a `double` and then correctly rounded to a `float`, the result is the same as rounding directly to a `float` **unless** the rounding to a `double` moved the value across a boundary where rounding to a `float` changes.

These boundaries exist only at the midpoints between two representable values, at the 24<sup>th</sup> bit of a significand (counting the most significant bit as the 0<sup>th</sup> bit). But the rounding to a `double` occurs at the 53rd bit. So rounding to `double` can cause a value to cross the `float` rounding boundary only if bits 24 to 53 have specific values, shown in the following cases.

[Somebody should check these; it is easy to make a mistake.]

Case 0:

```
               Bit 23 24 25-52 53 54…
Original            1  0 11…11  1 anything
Rounded to double   1  1 00…00  0 0… (53 above midpoint: rounds up, carries to higher bits)
Then to float       0  0 00…00  0 0… (24 at midpoint, 23 is odd: rounds up, carries into bit 22, not shown)
Directly to float   1  0 00…00  0 0… (24 below midpoint: rounds down)
```

Case 1:

```
               Bit 23 24 25-52 53 54…
Original            0  1 00…00  0 anything except all zeroes
Rounded to double   0  1 00…00  0 0… (53 below midpoint: rounds down)
Then to float       0  0 00…00  0 0… (24 at midpoint, 23 is even: rounds down)
Directly to float   1  0 00…00  0 0… (24 above midpoint: rounds up)
```

Case 2:

```
               Bit 23 24 25-52 53 54…
Original            0  1 00…00  1 0…
Rounded to double   0  1 00…00  0 0… (53 at midpoint, 52 is even: rounds down)
Then to float       0  0 00…00  0 0… (24 at midpoint, 23 is even: rounds down)
Directly to float   1  0 00…00  0 0… (24 above midpoint: rounds up)
```

Case 0 requires 31 bits have specific values, so it occurs one time in 2<sup>31</sup>, assuming values are effectively distributed uniformly. Case 1 is the same except it also requires that a one bit occur anywhere in infinitely many bits, the probability of which is effectively one. Case 2 requires infinitely many bits be zero, so it has a probability of zero. Aesthetically at least, cases 1 and 2 dovetail.

The combined probability of any of these cases occurring is 1 in 2<sup>30</sup>.

So, cases where rounding a `double` result to `float` produces a different result than directly calculating a `float` result are rare.

On top of that, most `pow` implementations are imperfect. They are not known to return correctly rounded results in all cases. (This is hard to implement.) So you may have imperfect results anyway. Rounding to `double` and then to `float` will not make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 2):

You could always write your own little function to do it.

```
public float power(final float base, final int power) {
    float result = 1;
    for( int i = 0; i < power; i++ ) {
        result *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

*EDIT: Some additional testing*

As people have pointed out in the comment section, this will return errors if the resulting float proves too large to be stored within a float value.

The following main method:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println( power(Float.MAX_VALUE, 2));
}
```

gave me the result:

```
Infinity
```

Obviously, my solution has its limitations.

*EDIT: Further Reading*

To avoid the limitation present, I wonder if you could use a double during the calculations, then convert them it a float just before returning. Either by using Math.pow() or altering the code above.

Keep in mind, this may well result in some precision issues which are explained in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075058/converting-from-double-to-float-in-java)

Comment: How do you think `float ^ someX` will *always* return a *float*?

Comment: This implementation is worse than a reasonable implementation of `pow()` with `double` arguments for most integer values of `power`.

Comment: This method will cause an overflow and return fake results if `result*base` returns a number that exceeds the maximum representable by `float`

Comment: I have made a typo when correcting the question. Your original solution is right, I do want the result to be a float. If a better answer won't come up soon I'll accept yours.

Comment: @snakile Cool, I've removed the bit about the result as a double.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use

```
Math.pow(x, p);
```

Your float x will be converted to a double even if you do not do it explicitly. The trouble though is when you get the returned value as a double and what you do with it then.

EDIT:
If it is required to have a method that returns a float you can still use the Math.pow and then include your conversion back from double to float and include your own logic for this.

```
public float myPow(float x, float p) {
    double dblResult = Math.pow(x, p);
    float floatResult = (float)dblResult; // <-- Change to something safe. It may easily overflow. 
    return floatResult;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually do need the result to be a float. I've made an edit to the question to clarify that.

Comment: You could still use Math.pow and take care of the result (like casting it back to float, beware of overflows though). Either solution you go for will require you to do some kind of handling or coding and it is more a matter of taste how you will deal with that.

Comment: I think you made a typo though, because now the question says you want to have the result as a double.

Comment: You're right. I fixed it. I want the result as a float.

Comment: There is no need for the comment “Change to something safe.” or for any change. If the conversion in `(float)dblResult` overflows, it will result in `inf`, which is what a `float` version of `pow` would have returned for the same arguments if it existed.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Perhaps so, but I wanted to mark (without leaving any doubt) the row where a change would take place to implement the functionality according to the requirements (which I would not have as I do not know all the details) and at the same time I wanted to provide a method that actually also will compile correctly.