# Java 8 stream average for float

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following model:

```
public class WeightChange {

    private float value;

    public float getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

and collection:

```
private List<WeightChange> weightChanges;
```

I have implemented function that gets average weight value using Java 8 features:

```
public float getAvgChangedWeight() {
    return (float) weightChanges.stream().mapToDouble(WeightChange::getValue).average().getAsDouble();      
}
```

Could you please help improve it because I don't think that casting to double is a good idea.

Also it throws an exception when the `weightChanges` collection is empty. How does one improve it in this case?

Comment: "I don't think that casting to double is a good idea" - in what way? What are you concerned about? It seems entirely reasonable to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting from double to float in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075058/converting-from-double-to-float-in-java)

Comment: @JonSkeet I just feel it :) Also, I have added one more case - it throws exception when weightChanges collection is Empty. How to improve it in this case ?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should always use `double` for calculations.  The only time you should ever use `float` is when you need to store huge arrays of numbers.

Comment: Float->double preserves accuracy, double->float loses accuracy.

Comment: So you have no specific concerns? That leaves very little for anyone answering to help you with. As for an empty collection - what does it mean to take the average of that? That's an entirely orthogonal question, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet can I manage the case with empty collection in stream() methods chain.. or just simple add one IF statement ?

Comment: @alexanoid: I don't know enough about Java streams to know yet (I know what I'd do in .NET). You could add least use `Collectors.summarizingDouble` and then check whether the count was 0.

Comment: and regarding my concerns - how this casting works from the performance side ? Will it affect the calculation speed somehow ?

Comment: @jameslarge Thanks, I'll refactor my code to use double

Comment: There aren't too many good reasons to use `float` (or `short`).  That's probably why the Java 8 designers left those out when setting up new stream classes and methods.

Comment: Well, `float`, `short`, or `byte` are relevant when it comes to *storage*, especially if you have large arrays of them. But a `Stream` doesn’t store any values.

Comment: Doing computations entirely in float is also roughly twice as fast as double (usual disclaimers about benchmarks apply) so if you care about that sort of thing, you might deliberately avoid double.

Comment: @Trejkaz: How often is floating-point computation speed significant for simple but data-heavy calculations (versus the time to get data to/from the CPU)?  A few years ago, reading many floats and accumulating as double would be likely faster than adding floats using floats for temporary results in any fashion that would yield decent precision (adding 65,535 values of type `float` directly may yield a result with less than a dozen significant bits; the job may be done using 65,535 floating-point additions while yielding better accuracy, but it's a bit trickier).

Comment: @supercat Good question. I don't really know if floats were faster because of the computation being faster or faster because it's less data being sent to the CPU, because the only thing giving me data was a benchmark tailored to our own use case. And in our case, I just saw the overall speed being doubled, but I was surprised to see that because people had been saying for years, "just use double, it isn't any slower". I assumed that perhaps the JRE didn't support SSE when people were saying that, or something like that.

Comment: @Trejkaz: SSE can do operate on 32-bit values faster than on 64-bit values when using vectorized code, but I'm unaware of any compilers that can vectorize "ordinary" floating-point math.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question, if you want to avoid the exception when the list is empty and return some `double` value, use `orElse` instead of `getAsDouble`:

```
return weightChanges.stream()
    .mapToDouble(WeightChange::getValue)
    .average()
    .orElse(Double.NaN);
```

Comment: Double.NaN - A constant holding a Not-a-Number (NaN)