# Validating int and float value all together

Tags: java

I am getting a value named `amount` in an object through its getter as shown below.

Let's say the object is `h` then

```
h.getAmount()
```

Now I need to develop a validator that will validate that `amount` should be of type integer and if it is not then it will throw the exception, I have developed that also as shown below

```
private  boolean isint (String amount){
    boolean isValid = true;
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(amount); 
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        isValid = false;
    }
     return isValid;
}
```

Now the issue is that `amount` coming from `h` is an integer such as `1234`, but it can also be a float such as `1258.26`. So in the case of float it throws a `NumberFormatException`.

How could I make it perfect for both the values whether it is integer or whether it is float?

Comment: how come system can give you non int value if you are not allowing non int number ?

Comment: Your getter should have specified that it returns an int or float? How come you process it as a `String` as a follow up?

Comment: It's the content of the string that *should* be a serialized integer value but *could* be a decimal.

Comment: An ugly way would be to determine if the string contains a `.` then act accordingly.

Comment: I suggest using `long` and `double` rather than `int` and `float` as these have double the precision which can save you some buggy behaviour at next to no cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `regex` like this:-

```
if (str.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+")) { // You can use the `\\d` instead of `0-9` too!
    // Is a number - int, float, double         
}
```

**[-+]?** - For the sign.

**[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+** - For the numbers and the decimal point between them.

**Update:-**

In case exponential needs to be handled too, then the below `regex` can be used.

```
String regex = "[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?";
```

Comment: I would consider `1.6e6` a float or double.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you have a function called `isInt` it should do exactly that -- check if it's an integer. No more and no less.

You could try something like that

```
enum VarType {
    INTEGER, FLOAT, STRING, EMPTY
}

private VarType getVarType(String amount){
     if (amount.length() ==0) {
       return VarType.EMPTY;
     }
     if (amount.contains(".")) { 
       try {
         Float.parseFloat(amount); 
       }
       catch(NumberFormatException e){
         return ValType.STRING;
       }
       return ValType.FLOAT;
     } else {
       try {
         Integer.parseInt(amount); 
       }
       catch(NumberFormatException e){
         return ValType.STRING;
       }
       return ValType.INTEGER;
     }
}
```

I would not recommend it though, because using exceptions in this way is really expensive. Exceptions should be used as their name suggests, to handle special cases, exceptions, and not as a standard flow.

**I would do it like this:**

```
public class ParseVarTest {

    static enum VarType {
        INTEGER, FLOAT, STRING, EMPTY
    }

    private static VarType getVarType(String amount){
        boolean onlyDigits = true;
        int dotCount = 0;
        if (amount == null) {
            return VarType.EMPTY;
        }
        String trimmed = amount.trim();
        if (trimmed.length() == 0) {
            return VarType.EMPTY;
        }
        int a=0;
        if (trimmed.charAt(0) == '-') {
            a++;
        }
        for (int max=trimmed.length(); a<max; a++) {
            if ( trimmed.charAt(a) == '.' ) {
                dotCount++;
                if (dotCount>1) break;
            } else if ( !Character.isDigit(trimmed.charAt(a)) ) {
                onlyDigits = false;
                break;
            }  
        }

        if (onlyDigits) {
            if (dotCount ==0) {
                return VarType.INTEGER;
            } else if (dotCount ==1) {
                return VarType.FLOAT;
            } else {
                return VarType.STRING;
            }
        }
        return VarType.STRING;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] vars = {"", "  ", "123", "-5123", "1234.41", "-1234.41", "-1234..41","a12312", "523sdf234sdf.123"};
        for (String var: vars) {
            System.out.print(var);
            System.out.print(": \t");
            System.out.println(getVarType(var));
        }
    }

}
```

It's quite long for such a simple task, but:

- no regexes
- at most a single scan of the string
- readable (IMO)
- fast

However, *this solution does not validate the range of the value*. String `10000000000` would still be recognized as a `VarType.INTEGER` even though the value could not fit into an `int` variable in Java.

Comment: You can have a number which is a valid `float` which does not contain a `.` but is not a valid `int` value. e.g. `10000000000`

Comment: @PeterLawrey yep, no value ranges taken into account here. Thanks for the remark. In such case the solution using exceptions will be better.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Double.parseDouble** ... (method name changed to `isNumber` to better reflect the meaning of the method) ...

```
private  boolean isNumber (String amount){
    boolean isValid = true;
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(amount); 
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        isValid = false;
    }
     return isValid;
}
```

... and could simplify to ...

```
private  boolean isNumber (String amount){
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(amount);             
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return false;            
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I suggest the OP use `double`, but if the OP is only using `int` or `float` this method can return true, for values which will not fit into either.

Comment: @PeterLawrey agreed. my answer assumes OP wants to allow a range of numeric values. From Double.MIN_VALUE to Double.MAX_VALUE. If OP wants to constrain to Float-size numerics, use parseFloat etc.

Comment: Neither of these values fit into a float or an int.

Comment: Need more info from OP, but I actually think this is what he wants to know ... "has a number been entered?" ... we don't have any info on what gets done with it ... or what size data type it should be constrained to.

Comment: Agreed, BigDecimal might be an option, but it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, it would be better to use `long` and `double` instead of `int` and `float`.

By the way, can't you simply check for a `float` ? If it is an `int`, than it can always be a `float`, [potentially rounded with loss of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781271/1654265).

```
public static boolean isFloat(String number){
    try {
       return !new Float(number).isNaN();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Running demo: https://ideone.com/UpGPsK

Output:

```
> 1234                 IS     a valid Integer or Float    
> 1234.56              IS     a valid Integer or Float    
> 1234.56.78           IS NOT a valid Integer or Float     
> abc                  IS NOT a valid Integer or Float     
> 2147483647           IS     a valid Integer or Float    
> 3.4028235E38         IS     a valid Integer or Float    
> -2147483648          IS     a valid Integer or Float    
> 1.4E-45              IS     a valid Integer or Float
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about integers or a few decimals, you're probably talking about *money* or *quantities*, for which **BigDecimal is ideal;**  and floating-point not really so good (due to rounding errors).

Otherwise, you're talking about a **double** floating-point value.

`new BigDecimal( str)` will parse an integer or decimal for you, but it will also accept exponents;  eg 1.4E2 means 140.

Perhaps you want to use a regex pattern to validate it first;

```
if (! str.matches( "[-+]?(\\d+)|(\\d*\\.\\d+)")) 
    throw new NumberFormatException();
```

This pattern accepts decimals without any leading digits, such as .14159 -- which should be allowable.