# Does Java's Math.pow round off the result?

Tags: java, math, floating-accuracy, pow

Today I came across a peculiar behavior of Math.pow(). I am not able to understand the output of the following java code:

```
long N1 = 999999999999999999L;
System.out.println("N1 : " + N1);

long N2 = (long) Math.pow(N1, 1);
System.out.println("N2 : " + N2);
```

I get the following output:

```
N1 : 999999999999999999
N2 : 1000000000000000000
```

I always thought that Math.pow() produces the exact result as long as the parameters passed to it are integers or longs provided there is no overflow (which is true in this case).

Comment: This code is converting from a long to a double and back... what happens if you do that conversion without Math.pow() at all? Does it not do the same thing?

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan You are correct! `long N3 = (long) (double) N1;`

Comment: `long` and `double` both take up 64 bits, and there are very many `double` values that can't be represented exactly with a `long`. Therefore, there must be very many `long` values that can't be represented exactly with a `double`.  You have found one of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

because it casts `long` to `double`

```
System.out.println((double)999999999999999999L);
```

outputs:

```
1.0E18
```

and

```
System.out.println((long)(double)999999999999999999L);
```

outputs:

```
1000000000000000000
```

- [why is that ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781086/loss-of-precision-int-float-or-double)

Comment: + 1, though since doubles are not printed exactly, it would be a better demonstration to write `System.out.println((long) (double) 999999999999999999L);`

Comment: thanks that helped me to understand what was happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigDecimal` for such calculations and not lose precision in converting between types:

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(999999999999999999L);
BigDecimal pow = b.pow(1);
```