# Is double division equal to integer division if there is no remainder?

Tags: java, floating-point, jvm

On the JVM, does division between two double values always yield the same exact result as doing the integer division?

With the following prerequisites:

- Division without remainder
- No division by zero
- Both `x` and `y` actually hold integer values.

E.g. in the following code

```
double x = ...;
int resultInt = ...;
double y = x * resultInt;
double resultDouble = y / x; // double division
```

does `resultDouble` always equal `resultInt` or could there be some loss of precision?

Comment: There are only 4 billion 32bit ints. You can test this simply by enumerating all values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if `x` and `y` are both in the `int` range, unless the division is `-2147483648.0 / -1.0`. In that case, the double result will match the result of integer division, but not `int` division.

If both division inputs are in `int` range, they are both exactly representable as `double`. If their ratio is an integer and the division is not `-2147483648.0 / -1.0` the ratio is in the `int` range, and so exactly representable as `double`. That `double` is the closest value to the result of the division, and therefore must be the result of the `double` division.

This reasoning does not necessarily apply if `x` and `y` are integers outside the `int` range.

Comment: Your statement is not always true: `-2147483648.0 / -1.0 != -2147483648 / -1`

Answer (score 4):

There are two reasons that assigning an int to a double or a float might lose precision:

- There are certain numbers that just can't be represented as a double/float, so they end up approximated
- Large integer numbers may contain too much precision in the lease-significant digits

So it depeands on how big the int is, but in Java a double uses a 52 bit mantissa, so will be able to represent a 32bit integer without lost of data.

The are fabolous examples in this two sites:

[1- Java's Floating-Point (Im)Precision](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/javas-floating-point-imprecision/240168744)

[2- About Primitive Data Types In Java](http://java.meritcampus.com/core-java-topics/primitive-data-types)

also check:

[Loss of precision - int -> float or double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781086/loss-of-precision-int-float-or-double)

Answer (score 3):

The statement is true with the exception of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, where the result of division of two integers may fall out of integer range.

```
    int n = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int m = -1;
    System.out.println(n / m);                          // -2147483648
    System.out.println((int) ((double)n / (double)m));  // 2147483647
```