# Double to Int without lossy precision

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors

The following declaration gives me a compile-time error *"Error:(19, 13) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int"*

```
int i1 = 10.0;

// Error:(19, 14) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
```

**Question 1**

I understand the error but can the compiler not infer - in this particular case - that there will be no loss of precision?

**Question 2**

If I explicitly convert the double to an `int` then it compiles fine (not even a warning) even though I am definitely losing precision in this example

```
int i2 = (int)9999999999999.999999999;
```

If I can't compile the first case - where no loss occurs - then why does this second example with the explicit conversion not even generate a compiler warning?

Comment: The first expression is compile time error which says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int`

Comment: Because that's what the people defining the Java language defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loss of precision - int -> float or double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781086/loss-of-precision-int-float-or-double)

Comment: first case is similar to a case where a method accepting int is passes a double as parameter. The 2 programmers may be involved one defining the method other passing the floating point value as parameter to the method. It is possible both programmers do not know each other intentions of definkng the method and calling the method. Compiler gives the error so that 2nd programmer where he can either convert the floating point to int himself. 2nd case of typecastig is clear case where programmer knows what he is doimg he is typecasting it Knowingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to question 1**

There is a loss of precision according to the compiler, because the compiler only sees that you have an int variable on the left and a double value on the right. The compiler is not so smart as to figure out that `10.0` will not lose precision when converted to an int.

The compiler could in theory be built to allow that statement to compile, but there is no real benefit in doing so. Almost no one writes `int x = 10.0`.

**Answer to question 2**

Indeed, there is a loss of precision, but why did the compiler not complain? Because you used a cast. You wrote `(int)`. This is you showing the compiler that you know what you're doing. By writing a cast, you are telling it that you are aware that there is a possible loss of precision.

Comment: well when you do `short s = 12`, 12 is of type `int` and the compiler *can* deduce no precision being lost...

Comment: @Eugene Yes, that's right. Here is my speculation: `short s = 12` makes a lot more sense than `int x = 10.0`. The latter feels weird - assigning a decimal to an integer, whereas the former is assigning an integer to an integer, which is why the compiler is designed to allow the former.

Comment: if only compilers where smarter than us, wait... :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, a compiler could infer that the specific example in #1 wouldn't actually loose precision based on the literal's value, but as you've seen - it doesn't.

The explicit cast signals to the compiler that you are aware of the situation an handling it, so the code actually compiles. Most IDEs, however, could be configured to emit a warning in such a situation too.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment of a `double` value to an `int` variable would require a [narrowing conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3), even if the value is a compile-time constant, and hence *requires* an explicit cast.

*Except* that an `int` (or `short` or `char`) constant value can be assigned to a `byte`, `short`, or `char` variable without casting, if the constant actually fits in the variables value range, as explicitly documented in the  Java Language Specification, section [5.2. Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> *Assignment contexts* allow the value of an expression to be assigned ([§15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)) to a variable; the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable.
>
> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion ([§5.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.1))
> - a widening primitive conversion ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2))
> - a widening reference conversion ([§5.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5))
> - a boxing conversion ([§5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)) optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.
>
> If, after the conversions listed above have been applied, the resulting type is a raw type ([§4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)), an unchecked conversion ([§5.1.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9)) may then be applied.
>
> In addition, **if the expression is a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`**:
>
> - **A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable**.
> - A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:
>
>   - `Byte` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `byte`.
>   - `Short` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `short`.
>   - `Character` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `char`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question

In theory this could be possible, well `javac` does not complain when doing:

```
short s = 12;
```

Even if  `12` here is a compile time constant of type `int`, so it can deduce that no precision is lost. I guess this is what the compiler team thought would be most appropriate.

Well when you `cast`  is a different story, it's like saying "trust me, I know what I'm doing", even if you loose precision.

Comment: Thanks, would have accepted your answer but I think Sweeper got there just before