# Why is int being cast to float in java?

Tags: java, casting

In this code

```
    public void display(int x, double y){
        System.out.println("Double");
    }
    public void display(int x, float y){
        System.out.println("Float");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        prog01 p = new prog01();
        p.display(4,5); //First Output
        p.display(4,5.0); // Second Output
    }
```

The outputs are:

```
Float
Double
```

The second output is understandable, but why is 5 being cast to float when it should have given an error?

Comment: Why should it give an error? The value is widen implicitly.

Comment: @akuzminykh Why didn't it widen to double?

Comment: Where does it say it should widen to `double` rather than `float`? What is the basis for your expectation?

Comment: @AyushBasak Check out the limits `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Float.MAX_VALUE`; a `double` is just not necessary.

Comment: In fairness, a `double` is needed to _precisely_ represent all values of type `int`.

Comment: [Loss of precision - int -> float or double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2781086/12323248)

Comment: @akuzminykh The confusion that I had was why does implicit casting happen in function overloading. I was expecting it to give an error as 5 is an `int` and it can't find a function with the same parameter data types.

Comment: @AyushBasak Yes, I know. I've just added a reference about what Louis has mentioned, which I should have mentioned as well.

Comment: @AyushBasak To your point: You can imagine the process of finding a method to be like so: 1) The compiler searches for a method that matches exactly those arguments and their types that you are passing. 2) If no method in 1) could be found, the compiler allows widenings for the search. In your case, the compiler finds the method `display(int, double)` because the `5` can be widen to `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widening Casting (Implicit) happens, `byte` -> `short` -> `int` -> `long` -> `float` -> `double`.
Here you pass integer, Since it doesn't have `long` as a type, the next one is `float`. That's why it's giving you `float`